# Flag as duplicate finds no results at all

Tags: bug

I tried to flag [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150297/why-is-the-intellisense-not-working-when-i-open-a-new-script-in-visual-studio) question as duplicate of [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/149013/visual-studio-intellisense-syntax-highlighting-not-recognizing-unity-types?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, but I get no results. Whatever I type in.

[image]

Comment: Aside from the answer posted below, the second question is already marked as a duplicate of the first question. Closing the first as a duplicate of the second would create circular duplicated question references. Why would you want that?

Comment: Because both are the same question so boths are duplicates

Comment: Oh, ok, well if we close both as a duplicate of the other, users won't be able to answer any of them. That won't allow users who would have _the_ solution to help those who have the issue.

Comment: Ok I see and agree that it is better.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't post more explanation on the thread when closing the duplicate yesterday. Thank you both for taking the time to clear this up. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I know exactly the question of which the question is a duplicate, I usually paste the URL of the other question in the text field:

[image]

And if finds it right away.

Comment: That worked, I get `This question has no accepted answer or upvoted answers`, so I can't flag it.

Comment: @Black The [help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) page has a clearer way to explain it than I would: _"The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place."_ With this in mind, redirecting traffic from a question that has answers to a questions that has no answer makes little sense. It's expected that the target answer has some quality content before we can redirect to it.